# Removing words from titles because they're in the tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, edits, title

I've seen 2-3 question edits where a word was removed from the title just because it also appeared in the tags. To me, this seems like a really bad idea. It makes the questions unclear since the tags aren't immediately next to the title all the time (e.g. Google results).

I guess I'd like some feedback on whether there is any kind of consensus on this, whether some argue that removing tags from title is actually good practice or if these were isolated incidents.

Comment: See the [FAQ item](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) for this on Meta SE.

Comment: Man, I was posting this very same question, some minutes ago, hehehe... The world is small.

Comment: I think sometimes having those words in the title helps focus the question in the main topic, mostly when all the tags are from "similar level".

Comment: @Will I'm not talking about titles like "Ordering lists is so hard #python #omgreally #yolo #tgif"

Comment: By all means edit away "crammed" titles. BUT it's **quite silly** when "naive moderators" instantly remove any tag that happens to be used in a well-written title.  "Naive moderating" by over-zealous newish moderators is always a bit of a problem on QA sites. In the example at hand there's a simple rule "even a machine could follow" -- "don't put tags in titles."  This can lead to over-zealous newish moderators "removing tags from titles" in a ridiculous manner. So just bear that danger in mind.  (Again, if you're talking about #this #sort #of #idiocy, just delete the whole question.)

Comment: I agree. I just know that I am searching for "BigInteger" and I am I often frustrated when have to go look in the tags or try and scroll down to see if its C# or Java.. both languages 'BigInteger' are similar.  When C# or Java is specified in this case it helps.  I think if it makes it easier for the user, in this case because of the C#/Java similarities on the topic of BigInteger, the language should be specified in the "..in Java" or "...in C#" format.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The top tag (by popularity) *is* part of the title in Google results, provided it isn't already in the title explicitly. Titles like:

```
[Python] Why doesn't the list remove work when looping?
```

are not particularly useful, as the page `<title>` tag will be prefixed with `python -` *anyway*.

For search engines, the other tags are also marked up (`<a href=".." rel="tag">...</a>`) and from a SEO perspective, they don't *have* to be in the title. For people browsing the site, tags are always prominently placed with the question.

As such, tags only have a place in the title if they are an organic part of it:

```
Why doesn't a Python dictionary let you remove items in a loop while JavaScript does?
```

might make sense.

**However**, a suggested edit that does *nothing but* remove tag words from the title should be rejected as too minor. Suggested edits should address most, if not all, issues in a post. A user that goes around doing nothing but title edits is wasting everyone's time for a reputation gain only.

See the [Meta SE discussion on the subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) a well.

Comment: They also fixed spelling, so I restored the tag to the title and kept the spelling fixes.

Comment: Just looked at some google results and wow you're right never noticed that. I still feel like it belongs in the title, but if such an edit shows up again, should I approve it? Is there any kind of agreement on this?

Comment: The outstanding phrase here is **if they are an organic part of it** .. good one.

Comment: It's true that keywords should be an organic part of the title... and the correct action when there's a keyword list, is not to remove it, but to find a way to make it organic.

Answer (score 8):

A lot of people misunderstand that guidance to not put tags in the title.

You aren't supposed to use the title or question body as a keyword list, e.g. we often see people title their question as "Ambiguous overload (C++) (templates) (variadic functions)". That's not appropriate.

Listing germane information in the question title and body, even if it is also listed in the tags, is completely appropriate, and always has been. No thanks to a few editors who keep trying to remove it.  Keyword lists in titles should preferably be changed into meaningful phrases, e.g. "Why does my C++ compiler complain about ambiguous overload only when I add a variadic version?", not simply removed.

Comment: While this is good advice whenever it's practical to follow, some tags just do not belong in most questions' titles. For example, roughly 95% of questions that put their IDE tag in the title don't need it there. (And probably 50+% of questions with OS tags, and so on.)

Comment: @Nathan: Problem is, the asker isn't equipped to answer that.  If they knew which information was relevant and which wasn't, they wouldn't have to ask the question (in most cases).  So we expect the question to provide a comprehensive description of the problem and where it occurs, and the title to summarize that.  At some point after the experts figure out what was and wasn't relevant, the title can be edited down so future visitors can recognize their problem shares the essential aspects... but in my experience, the "don't use tags in titles" comment is never driven by that expertise.

Comment: That's what tags are for: put everything that could reasonably be relevant there, but only those things you're almost sure are relevant in the title. (And, of course, most question titles are astonishingly bad anyway.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy: So, I'm all for editing question titles to make them clear and accurate descriptions of the problem.  But that means an editor is saying "I know what about this description is important, and I'm rewriting the title to make that clear", not "Titles shouldn't contain tags (I heard once on meta), I'm rewriting the title to take them out".  The latter is NEVER a legitimate approach.  If you come across tag lists in titles, but don't have the expertise to know (with 99% certainty) which ones affect the answer, improve the style without removing words, not even OS or IDE names.

Comment: Fair enough: editing substantial details like that *do* always require at least enough expertise to be reasonably certain you're correct in the particular case; I'm certainly not advocating blind adherence to a rule.