# Tag in question title battle

Tags: discussion, tags, title

I've recently bumped into "[How do I set the text of a GtkTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292286/how-do-i-set-the-text-of-a-gtktextview)" via Google, which I thought would be helpful to me, but it wasn't. (The question was about C#/GTK#, and I was looking for a C/GTK answer.)

I've edited the original question (*Setting the text of a GtkTextView*) to include the word GTK# (*Setting the text of a GtkTextView in **GTK#***) to save some time for others having the same problem and for possible SEO. My edit was approved, then shortly after, someone changed the title to ***How do I set*** the text of a GtkTextView in GTK#**?**, which was reverted to *How do I set the text of a GtkTextView?*, with the following comment: "removed tag from title".

According to "[Why is removing tags from the title suggested so often?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often)" here in Meta, my initial idea was good. What should I do in such a situation? Should I start an "edit war" and add my edit again?

Please note that I've read "[Removing words from titles because they're in the tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251859/removing-words-from-titles-because-theyre-in-the-tags)", where it's explained that the search results in Google include the most popular tag already. In this particular case, it's misleading, since **gtk** is the most popular tag, not **gtk#**. Or maybe we could just remove the gtk tag?

What's the best course of action here?

**EDIT**: In a comment below, Cody Gray asked this: "Who gives a darn if there's a question mark or not? Who cares if it says GTK# or GtkTextView? Both seem equally valid and descriptive titles to me. "

`GtkTextView` does *not* hold any information regarding the language it is used in. To make it clear, the solution for C# looks something like this:

```
textview1.Buffer.Text = "Some sample text that will be displayed."
```

And the solution for C looks something like this:

```
GtkTextBuffer *buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(textview1);
gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, "Some sample text that will be displayed.", -1);
```

Now, one could argue that the internal logic of the two is the same (get the buffer from the `GtkTextView` and set it's text property), but still, I don't feel that the questions / solutions are interchangable. Unless of course, for example, it's acceptable to answer a Python question with a Haskell answer, which is just plain silly IMHO.

Comment: No, don't get into an edit war. Not for any reason, but especially not for *this* reason. The point is to get a descriptive title up there. Who gives a darn if there's a question mark or not? Who cares if it says GTK# or GtkTextView? Both seem equally valid and descriptive titles to me.

Comment: @CodyGray People looking for a C answer but finding a C# answer *do* care. A C# answer is not a solution for a C question, and vice versa. "GtkTextView" is *not* descriptive *at all*, it could be any programming language that has GTK bindings, C, C#, D, Python, Haskell, Lua, Perl, Ruby, Pascal, PHP, etc. Please see my edit for further clarification.

Comment: The *tags* tell you the language. You cannot put everything in the title. I don't see this as a real problem. The title covers the important stuff, which is the use of the Gtk library.

Comment: @CodyGray If the question is about "the use of the Gtk library", is it OK to add my solution for the C language, even though the tags tell it's C#? People working with C **will** find this question if it remains like this.

Comment: I don't get the point.  Use [tags] to select the proper target audience.  That's what SO users look at first, most C# users will never see a C question.  Your title is what they look at next.

Comment: Why not just add the language tag for what this is? If the language tag isn't relevant, the title change isn't relevant. If the language tag *is* relevant, then change the title to match the correct naming convention used.

Comment: @HansPassant If you google "c gtk gtktextview set text stackoverflow" you will find the C# question I've linked. I tried to address this problem by changing the title to tell that it's for C#. This might not be the best approach, so I posted this question to find out what *is*.

Comment: The question isn't properly tagged, it should have used the [c#] tag.  Which also automatically changes the title and the google hits.

Comment: @HansPassant Sounds reasonable, thank you. I've added the C# tag. (Such a simple solution. I feel kinda n00bish.)

Comment: @kraxor Note that there's also a [GTK#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gtk%23) tag, and if the question is *only* about GTK# the GTK tag should probably go. Anyway that question is really poor quality. It's a "how to do X?" question showing no reasearch nor effort whatsoever.

Answer (score 29):

As suggested by Hans Passant in the comments, the best solution seems to be to add the [C#] tag to the question, as it will dominate the less popular [gtk] tag and solve all problems at once.

Comment: If the question really is specific to GTK#, and not applicable to other GTK bindings, you could also remove the [tag:gtk] tag and just leave it with [tag:gtk#] (and optionally [tag:c#]).

Answer (score 10):

[As per Meta.StackExchange's rules for a good title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title), putting some of the tags into the title is okay, if it's part of the question sentence.  For one of the "good" examples:

> Move an existing X11 window via command line?

The "no tags in titles" rule is meant to prevent things like this from happening, which is exactly what tags are meant for:

> X11: Move an existing window via command line?

Since `in GTK#` flowed pretty naturally as part of the question title, the question title should have been left as-is, however it was found.

The OP didn't include it in the title, so there was no reason to add it, as long as it was in the tags.  However, since the way it was added didn't actually violate that rule, there was no reason to roll it back, either.

So, just let the issue drop.

Comment: We sometimes get a misinterpretation of the 'no tags' rule: if key words are added into the title, they are fine. They are regarded as tags (for the purposes of removing them) if they are separated by dashes, brackets, bars etc, since the result is not a natural English sentence. See [my answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/472495) for more.

Comment: Both of those titles are equally good.  What would be horrible is "Move an existing window via command line?" with a tag of X11 - and you see those kinds of uninformative titles all the time.

Comment: @James: IMO, the community doesn't believe they are equally good. If there are other edits that would make it worthwhile, the second one would be changed to be more like the first. FWIW, I tend to agree with that policy - if words are being used as tags, the poster may as well use the tag system.

Comment: @halfer Yeah, that's exactly what this answer says.

Comment: @Izkata: yes, I just wanted to clarify the difference between tags and keywords (as I understand it, anyway).

Comment: I think the rule you're talking about is more like "titles should read well" - that's a completely different rule than no tags, since "no tags" could result in the terrible, awful, no-good title of "Move an existing window via command line" without the X11 (since X11 is a tag).  That's my only problem with talking about a "no tags" rule.

Comment: And I agree that I overstated things by saying that they're equally good - you're right that one is better than the other.