# Repeated editing by same user

Tags: discussion

I just asked a question with the word 'jQuery' in the title. Without the library name the questions is much more ambiguous and despite Stack Overflow allowing tags to be indexed it still would mean if that question came up in the search results I would assume it was related to general JavaScript and ignore it (because the question would be relevant to plain JavaScript).

A user edited it to change the title, and I rolled back the edit to keep the question unambiguous. The user then proceeded to [re-edit my question another half dozen times](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25247116/revisions).

I try to follow the Stack Overflow rules and as far as I am aware it is not a rule/policy that I can't include the library name in the title. It just seems to be down to the user's opinion, so my question is, why is a user allowed to repeatedly modify a question even though the author is undoing it? And is there a way to stop it?

(And also, is it actually a rule I'm breaking?)

Comment: Did you include the tag `jQuery`?  If so, then that was all you needed to identify the question and it didn't need to be in the title.  I'd suggest reading [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: @bluefeet I did and it identifies the question on SO, but not on Google where I would see the tile but not the tags, which was my point. I've read that post already, which is what makes me think it seem jsut to be opinion, not a hard rule

Comment: And opinion is mixed, The second answer on that thread says "Please do not remove key words that happen to be tags when doing so makes the titles muddier."

Comment: The general consensus is to not include tags in the title.

Comment: @NickCardoso: You are making an incorrect assumption; the main tag (by total question count) is added to the title indexed by Google.

Comment: @NickCardoso: for example, using `Concrete5` in your question [Concrete5 - Why is my block controller set() not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25191921) is entirely redundant.

Comment: I would also note that you should _not_ get into an edit war.  Make the first rollback, then if it gets edited again, flag for a moderator with a custom flag explaining your concerns.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256724/tag-in-question-title-battle

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: It's not an assumption - I've just tested with some jQuery questions and the results did not include the tag in the title unless it was actually part of the title. Also again that's opinion, I don't see why thats redundant when block and controller arent terms specific to just that one platform

Comment: @NickCardoso: I said the *main tag* is included; if `jquery` is not already part of the title *and* it is the main tag, then the title for the page will be prefixed with `jquery - `.

Comment: @nick because the page title would still be "concrete5 - Why is my block controller set() not working?"

Comment: If it's a logical part of the question then it's fine.  I don't like your general title pattern, looking at your questions on [main]; "Android - some stuff" isn't really appropriate.  If it is "How do I make an element something work in Android", that's okay, but just prefacing with "Tag - question" isn't appropriate or necessary.  Google _does_ look at the tag in indexing the question, so it won't be surfaced in irrelevant searches (subject to usual Google).

Comment: Yes I read that it indexed tags, which I didn't know before today, but I haven't seen any examples of the tag included on search result titles. I just tried https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery+copy+element+value+stackoverflow and the second answer has no mention it's related to jQuery, even though it's the first tag for the question

Comment: It seems to work sometimes/not work sometimes, honestly; looking for top jQuery answers I don't see one, but javascript does ([this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263839/how-to-fill-in-a-text-field-with-drop-down-selection) for example), and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177477/update-on-certain-field) in SAS works just fine - google either's title.  But, the [tag:jquery] version of the first one doesn't say either [tag:jquery] or [tag:javascript], for some reason.  Dunno if that's a bug, or something I don't understand.

Comment: (The title is "how to clone content of a div to another div - Stack Overflow", I should add, because google personalises results)

Comment: @NickCardoso: This applies to the `<title>` tag in the HTML head, which is what Google indexes. The top result from [a sample search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22How+do+I+test+one+variable+against+multiple+values%3F%22) for example shows that Google indexed the question title *with* `python`. Moreover, the tags are marked up using the [schema.org microformat](http://schema.org/), a Google-sponsored standard.

Comment: @NickCardoso: the `how to clone` post was from 2010, from *before* the tags were included in the title. I edited the post (removed the thanks and hi) and now it is included. Next index run and Google will include the tag.

Comment: I see, I'll try to pay attention to what Google does with my future question titles then to see. @Joe I didn't spot your comment before. Flagging a moderator seems like a good idea, would I not get penalised for abusing the flagging system though? Is it intended to be used that way?

Comment: @Nick Cardoso: That is a perfectly acceptable use of flags. Any sort of dispute between users is one for a moderator to step in.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks for clarifying @MartijnPieters as to why some did and some didn't.

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes for this question. It's a reasonable question for clarification. Are you downvoting it because you don't agree with my view on whether including a tag in the title is acceptable? That hardly seems reasonable.

Comment: @NickCardoso Downvotes on meta are often used to indicate disagreement. [Officially](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), they are only supposed to be used that way on feature requests, but in practice they aren't. People could also be downvoting re. "as far as I am aware it is not a rule/policy that I can't include the library name in the title", since this is addressed in a longstanding [FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) and has been discussed numerous times on meta; asking a new question indicates lack of research.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You weren't forcing a tag into your title, so it was fine.

> jQuery Element being moved instead of Cloned

is a better title than

> Element being moved instead of Cloned

What we absolutely don't want to see is:

> Element being moved instead of Cloned [jQuery]

Your original title should have been left alone.  It would have been a lot better if you could have made it a complete question, though.

> Why is this jQuery code moving an element instead of cloning it?

Comment: That's my view. And the post by Jeff Atwood seems to agree with me/us. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103563/can-we-prevent-titles-with-an-unnecessary-tag-in-them/105991#105991

Comment: @NickCardoso Since there's really no such thing as a "jQuery element" I can kind of see why someone would want to edit that title. I would have rearranged it (see my edit) instead of just removing the tag word though.

Comment: I'll try to phrase questions as entire questions from now on, but as for this example I assume you can see the comments as well - I did say to the guy it becomes ambiguous with it removed but he was allowed to make the exact same edit repeatedly, it does seem ridiculous. If it's not a *rule* you could flag a question for, then it doesn't seem to make sense to allow someone to make the same change over and over

Comment: @NickCardoso Yeah, they really shouldn't do that. People are encouraged to edit, but once the original author rolls back you're supposed to leave it alone.