# Why was the second tag automatically prepended to the question title?

Tags: support, tags, title

Yesterday I asked this question, [Which is the best way to create NSString from an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379558/ios-which-is-the-best-way-to-create-nsstring)

Today, when I checked it again, "int" was added to the title (I believe that should be "integer").

[image]

I found this, [How do I set the text of a GtkTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292286/how-do-i-set-the-text-of-a-gtktextview) based on this, [Tag in question title battle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256724/tag-in-question-title-battle), which says that to make questions more relevant to users, tags may be (should be?) added to the questions' titles.

Now the question is, why "int"?

If you can see in the question that I asked, there's five tags I've added,

[image]

[int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int) is at the 2nd position, so why did SE's algorithm choose it?

1. Was it a random selection? I'm thinking NO.
2. Based on first occurrence keyword in the question? Chances are that.
3. Maximum use of particular keyword in the question? Wrong; I used `NSString` more than `int`.
4. Someone (at SE) read my question and updated its title field (in the database) - because "int" isn't added to question itself, except in the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int) comes first because your title already contains the most popular tag ([nsstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsstring)), there's nothing more to it. If your title also had `int` in it, then the type conversion tag would have been used.

Side note 1: your tag selection is pretty bad. Drop the two generic "efficient" tags, and add a language tag. [int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int) is not very useful either, but sort of makes sense with the conversion tag.

Side note 2: your title isn't great either, since it doesn't mention any sort of conversion. And prefixing with a tag isn't good - add the tag for [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) if it is relevant (I don't think it is) or the framework you're working with ([cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch), thanks to @Josh Caswell). Otherwise just mention the environment in your question.

Comment: Agreed that the tagging is pretty unhelpful. The framework tag would actually be better than the language tag in this case, though: [tag:cocoa-touch] (although the answer would be the same for [tag:cocoa]). I've added that in preference to [tag:int].

Comment: "If your title also had int in it, then the type conversion tag would have been used." – Correction: At least currently, if the 2 most popular tags are already in the post title, then no tag will be prepended to the title.

Answer (score 4):

> Was it a random selection? I'm thinking NO.

You are right, it is not a random selection. It is based on some logic

> Based on first occurrence keyword in the question? Chances are that.

Usually first tag of the post, sorted by popularity, is used. However if the first tag is already used in post title then the system would use second tag. In your case, [nsstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsstring) is already present in the title so [int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/int) is added to post title. Its is mainly done for SEO purposes as Google likes keywords to be present in page title.

Reference: [Which tag is added to the page title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title)