# Why are cleared information about the programming language from questions?

Tags: discussion

When I have a question: "What to do with something in the programming language?" (Substitute your favorite language.)
The information about which programming language is being used (the name of the language) is deleted from "title". Why?

*It is the pursuit of generality questions? = One problem and multiple examples of solutions in multiple programming languages.
Must answers to one question be for multiple languages when the question was on a particular language - about a specific problem in the code?* - That's probably not the purpose.

I see many questions about the problem and these questions have information about the programming language at the end of the question.

*Why was my question adjusted?* - Tags should not be directly on the title of question? In some places, there are no tags by title of question.

When I see a list of questions, I do not see an overview of the tags that specify the problem area. For example, in overview column [=>>>](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZFEUkInjCwnW8u-ZuIOAoJtXVeyW4UIt/view?usp=sharing) placed next to the issues discussed. Then I do not know what language to this problem applies.

Will the tags be displayed with questions anywhere in the future?

Also, tags at the end of the question (long problem) are not visible. I can see the title and the text, but I do not see where the problem belongs.

Wait a minute. I have to scroll to the end. Aha! I already know it.

Edit:

> For @MikeMcCaughan: *Can you provide a screenshot of the list of question you're talking about?*
>
> [Picture 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZFEUkInjCwnW8u-ZuIOAoJtXVeyW4UIt/view?usp=sharing)
>
> [Picture 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hUDIbobVKNt4TacFauAIECTo8HkxqiI6/view?usp=sharing)
>
> In these columns are not displayed tags. There are questions that contain the name of the language. So what are the rules for naming the language? In the beginning? For example: "Language - question?" At the end? For example: "Question in language OR with language?"
>
> Where tags are missing (case described above), the question title could be generated.
> For example: Tags: "Language", Title: "Question?" => Title: "Language - Question?"

Edit 2:

> For @HovercraftFullOfEels: *This is what question tags are for. You add a tag to the specific programming language of your question, and you don't put it in the title.*
>
> Tag management needs to be modified. At first sight I can not see any tags (see picture).
>
> [Picture 3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DIDAGj_8HenQxvuy_4gue-3xH8yPNzXy/view?usp=sharing)
>
> The picture shows possible revision of the appearance.

Comment: This is what question tags are for. You add a tag to the specific programming language of your question, and you don't put it in the title.

Comment: The tags show up when you open the question. They show up in the title of the HTML. They show up in Google search results. As far as I know, they should show up in the list of questions... Can you provide a screenshot of the list of question you're talking about?

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251859/removing-words-from-titles-because-theyre-in-the-tags